# Angularjs not updating the view of ng-repeat after the model updates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a "menu directive" that refuses to update the items in the html view when the model changes. I'm using angular js with a for-each statement.
Here is the minimum code I have stripped it down to.

The directive:

```
export function SideNavbarDirective() {
    'ngInject';

    let directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/sideNavbar/sideNavbar.html',
        scope: {
        },
        controller: SideNavbarController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
}

class SideNavbarController {
    constructor($scope, $timeout) {
        'ngInject';

        $scope.myItems = [
            {
                displayName:"1",
                highlight:true,
            },
            {
                displayName: "2",
                highlight: false,
            },
            {
                displayName: "3",
                highlight: false,
            },
        ];

        $timeout(() => {
            $scope.myItems[0].highlight = false;
            $scope.myItems[1].highlight = true;
            $scope.myItems.length = 2;
            $scope.$apply()
        }, 4000);

    }
}
```

The html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myItems" layout="row">
    <div flex layout="column">
            <div layout="row">
                <span>{{item.displayName | translate}}</span><span flex=""></span><span ng-show="{{item.highlight}}">*</span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initial view:

```
1* 
2
3
```

After the timer:

```
1* 
2
```

Expected result after the timer:

```
1 
2*
```

As you can se removing an item is reflected. But changing the content of the objects in the array goes by unnoticed by angular. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I updated the HTML to just print the value of the highlight property instead.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myItems" layout="row">
    <div flex layout="column">
            <div layout="row">
                <span>{{item.displayName | translate}}</span><span flex=""></span><span>{{item.highlight}}</span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I get:
Initial view:

```
1 true
2 false
3 false
```

After the timer:

```
1 false
2 true
```

So, now I get the expected values. WTF!
The problem must be with the ng-show expression or what? I'm more confused than ever.

Comment: Try to watch the changes in the array by $scope.$watch and as soon as the array changes, the directive must have the latest changes by adding $scope.$apply to reflect changes.

Comment: Hmm, In desperation I did put in a $scope.$apply() last in the timeout function as you can see in the example. But that did not make any difference. Also. I don't think that should be needed since $timeout should trigger the apply anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No curly braces needed in `ng-show`, so it should be `ng-show="item.highlight"`.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Now it works perfectly. This was almost embarrassing :)